# Extracting file numbers from file names in r and looping through files

Tags: r, for-loop, import

I have a folder full of .txt files that I want to loop through and compress into one data frame, but each .txt file is data for one subject and there are no columns in the text files that indicate subject number or time point in the study (e.g. 1-5). I need to add a line or two of code into my loop that looks for strings of four numbers (i.e. each file is labeled something like: "4325.5_ERN_No_Startle") and just creates a column with 4325 and another column with 5 that will appear for every data point for that subject until the loop gets to the next one. I have been looking for awhile but am still coming up empty, any suggestions?

I also have not quite gotten the loop to work:

```
path = "/Users/me/Desktop/Event Codes/ERN task/ERN text files transferred"
out.file <- ""
file <- ""           
file.names <- dir(path, pattern =".txt")         
for(i in 1:length(file.names)){
  file <- read.table(file.names[i],header=FALSE, fill = TRUE)
  out.file <- rbind(out.file, file)
}
```

which runs okay until I get this error message part way through:

Error in read.table(file.names[i], header = FALSE, fill = TRUE) : 
  no lines available in input

Comment: could try using `try()` around the read.table and see if it is because the file is empty. printing out what loop you are in when it dies can also help you identify the file that may be the issue.

Comment: error aside, it would be faster to go with `file<-lapply(file.names, read.table, header=F, fill=T)` followed by `out.file <- do.call(rbind, file)`

Comment: I always throw a `print(file.names[i])` in a loop that's causing an error. This way you can inspect the guilty file yourself. Also just use `for (ff in file.names)` -- the loop will automatically go through elements of `file.names` for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using regex to parse the file name for study period and subject, both of which are then binded  in a `lapply` of `list.files`:

```
path = "path/to/text/files"

# ANY TXT FILE WITH PATTERN OF 4 DIGITS FOLLOWED BY A PERIOD AND ONE DIGIT
file.names <- list.files(path, pattern="*[0-9]{4}\\.[0-9]{1}.*txt", full.names=TRUE)

# IMPORT ALL FILES INTO A LIST OF DATAFRAMES AND BINDS THE REGEX EXTRACTS
dfList <- lapply(file.names, function(x) {
                    if (file.exists(x)) {
                        data.frame(period=regmatches(x, gregexpr('[0-9]{4}', x))[[1]],
                                   subject=regmatches(x, gregexpr('\\.[0-9]{1}', x))[[1]],
                                   read.table(x, header=FALSE, fill=TRUE),
                                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
                    }
                 })

# COMBINE EACH DATA FRAME INTO ONE
df <- do.call(rbind, dfList)

# REMOVE PERIOD IN SUBJECT (NEEDED EARLIER FOR SPECIAL DIGIT)
df['subject'] <- sapply(df['subject'], 
                        function(x) gsub("\\.", "", x))
```

Comment: this worked wonderfully,  but your last line of code is not getting rid of the period any thoughts on why that is?

Comment: Great! For period, what results instead? See edit with use of `stringsAsFactors = F` in the `data.frame()` which avoids using `as.character()` in sapply. If that doesn't work, see if there are other periods in filename with single digit just behind it.

Comment: got it to work, super easy fix thanks so much. just had to change it to: df$subject <- sapply(df$subject, 
                        function(x) gsub("\\.", "", as.character(x)))

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `tryCatch`which basically would give you a NULL instead of an error.

```
file <- tryCatch(read.table(file.names[i],header=FALSE, fill = TRUE), error=function(e) NULL))
```